# Xcode build - stuck on Compiling Swift source files

Tags: xcode, xcode8

When building my project in Xcode 8 GM, Xcode sticks on "Compiling Swift source files". It also never finishes indexing my project at any point.

I've looked at the similar questions but none of those answers work for me.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift inference was the problem.

There were several instance where I was inferring a dictionary type that for some reason grew exponentially as the dictionary had more values.

Comment: Could you give some insight into how you found the offending dictionaries?

Comment: It was good-old comment out and build. In my case my code looked like this: `let propertiesInfo: [String: Any?]? = ["key": myValue]` so it might be worth looking for explicit casts or values with `Any` or `Any?` types.

Comment: As a note, I'm still investigating why this exponential growth happens in my case..

Comment: @AdamCarter Okay thank you for laying that out, however, I can't comment the code im using because it is like populating my models and a lot of swift inference is taking place there, how should i go about it, or for that matter around it? My project never runs unless and until I comment a whole lot of my model and then a lot of values are left out. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you used lot of Concatination of string like

```
var fun=0;
var tempvalue=2;
var result="some data"+fun+" more data"+tempvalue;
```

**Transform it to**

```
var result="somedata \(fun) more data \(tempvalue)";
```

Because swift compiler take lots of time to analyse overloding methods of "+" operator

Answer (score 0):

Clean Build Folder (Cmd+Shift+Opt+K) usually helps me in this case, but time to time issue returns.

Comment: I am struggling with issue from last 3 days . I tried everything mentioned.  Please help. Just added a core data file and it's connection. I deleted credata and added it again. I install pods again. And even formatted my system ..  and set up all newly..Please help

Comment: @Charmi Any way you resolved it at all? Im facing the problem.

Comment: @cookiemonsta  it was regarding Dictionary. Key and Value

Comment: @Charmi ... and you did what instead of the Dictionary, key and value?

Comment: @cookiemonsta I defined type For Dictionay i.e let dict : [String:Anything] = ["key": value]

Comment: @Charmi Thanks for the prompt reply. Yeah I figured that out after exploring it for 2 days. Thanks again